Supabase Cookies Not Being Set in Production Environment - Nuxt3
I'm having an issue with Supabase cookies not being set in my production environment after building my app. Here are the details:
Environment URLs Tested:

http://[::]:3000/ - Cookies not set
http://0.0.0.0:3000/ - Cookies not set
http://localhost:3000/ - Cookies set successfully
http://127.0.0.1:3000/ - Cookies set successfully
http://192.168.1.3:3000/ - Cookies not set (ipconfig > en0)

In my local development environment, Supabase cookies are set correctly when accessing the app through localhost or 127.0.0.1. However, when using other IP addresses or the 0.0.0.0 or [::] addresses, the cookies are not set.
Steps Taken:

Ran yarn build to build the app.
Used yarn preview to serve the built app.
Tested with the URLs mentioned above.

I'm not sure if the IP addresses I used are causing the issue or if there's a configuration problem in my Supabase setup. Has anyone faced a similar issue or can provide some guidance on how to resolve this?
Additional Information:

The URL 192.168.1.3 was obtained using ipconfig > en0.
My Supabase configuration is standard and works fine in development mode with localhost and 127.0.0.1.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
